# Return to directory location prior to cd-ing to home directory

Tags: shell, directory, cd-command

As is well known, `cd` without an argument changes one's current directory to their home directory.  I am wondering if there is any way, after using the `cd` command like this, to return to the directory location one was at prior to running `cd`?

Generalizing, is there any way of returning to a previous directory after one has `cd`-ed to another directory?  It seems very possible that the answer to these two questions will be the same but in case it isn't I kept them both separate, because the first question is the main one I would like answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:

```
cd -
```

or

```
cd "$OLDPWD"
```

(You can omit the quotes if the directory name contains no whitespace or wildcard characters.)

These work in all POSIX-style shells (bash, ksh, zsh, …). `cd -` also works in tcsh and fish.

Comment: I tried with tcsh.  `cd -` worked just fine, but `cd $OLDPWD` just takes me back to my home directory.

Comment: @Joshua This means that `tcsh` doesn't set `OLDPWD` so it expanded `cd $OLDPWD` into `cd`.

Comment: but when I do `echo $OLDPWD` I get the path to my home directory as output.

Comment: `cd -` and `cd "$OLDPWD"` work in all POSIX shells. Tcsh has `cd -` but not `OLDPWD`.

Answer (score 4):

I often times use `pushd` and `popd` to avoid this problem.

#### Example

```
$ pwd
/home/saml/tst/134317

$ ls -l
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Jun  3 16:05 dir1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Jun  3 16:05 dir2
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Jun  3 16:05 dir3
```

Now let's go to `dir1`.

```
$ pushd dir1
~/tst/134317/dir1 ~/tst/134317

$ pwd
/home/saml/tst/134317/dir1
```

And to `dir2`:

```
$ pushd ../dir2/
~/tst/134317/dir2 ~/tst/134317/dir1 ~/tst/134317

$ pwd
/home/saml/tst/134317/dir2
```

Now back to where ever we just came from:

```
$ popd
~/tst/134317/dir1 ~/tst/134317

$ pwd
/home/saml/tst/134317/dir1
```

You can see what directories are on your stack with the `dirs` command:

```
$ dirs
~/tst/134317/dir1 ~/tst/134317
```

The directory you're currently in is the directory furthest to the left.

```
~/tst/134317/dir1
```

The directory we'll "pop" to is the directory next to it on the right.

```
~/tst/134317
```

It continues to "push" directories on the left side as you add them, and "pops" them from the left side as well.

Answer (score 2):

With bash, an alternative to "cd -" could be pushd/popd, it allows to work with a directory stack :

```
cd <path1> => move to <path1>
pushd <path2> => move to <path2>
pushd <path3> => move to <path3>
...
popd => return to <path2>
popd => return to <path1>
```